# Django ModelForm individual fields not validated when overriding clean() on Model

Tags: django, validation, model, field, modelform

I am using standard Django Models and ModelForms.

On the Model, I am overriding the `clean()` method to check that 2 fields in combination are valid. I am having `validators[]`, not nulls etc defined on other fields.

In the ModelForm, I am not modifying anything. I only set the corresponding Model in the ModelForm's Meta class.

When I try to create a new object through the form, the **individual** fields in the ModelForm/Model **are not validated** when I call `form.is_valid()` in the View. According to the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) the `is_valid()` method on the Form should call the Model's `clean_fields()` method (first).

This doesn't seem to work when you submit a form without a Model instance (or a new instance not in the db). When I'm editing an existing object, all is well. It nicely triggers invalid values in individual fields before calling the Model's `clean()` method.

**When I remove the overridden `clean()` method from my Model, all is well.** Individual fields are validated both when creating new objects and editing existing ones.

I have also tested this with the admin module's forms. It has exactly the same behaviour.

So the question is, why does overriding the `clean()` method on my Model prevent the ModelForm validating the individual fields before calling the `clean()` method to test additional cross-field stuff???

Note that I am not validating the ModelForm. All validation is on the Model itself.

Model:

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    from_date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False, validators=[...])
    to_date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False, validators=[...])
    (...)    
    def clean(self):
        errors = []
        # At this point I expect self.to_date already to be validated for not null etc.
        # It isn't for new Model instances, only when editing an existing one
        if self.to_date < self.from_date:
            errors.append(ValidationError("..."))
```

ModelForm:

```
class TestForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Survey
```

View (to render blank form for new Model data entry):

```
(...)
if request.method == "POST":
    survey_form = TestForm(request.POST)
    if '_save' in request.POST:
        if survey_form.is_valid():
            survey_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(next_url)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(next_url)
else:
    survey_form = TestForm()

context = {'form': survey_form}
(...)
```

Comment: show some code please.

Comment: Perhaps calling parent class `clean` method first inside `clean` will do the trick? `super(Survey, self).clean()`

Comment: Usually the validation should be done at form level. If you are worried about admin side you can point your model form to be used inside in admin as well.

Comment: @AamirAdnan tried that, does not work. Also, `clean()` does not call `clean_fields()`. What does work is to call `super(Survey, self).clean_fields()` explicitly form `clean()`. But that's should not be needed. Plus I get strange behaviour that the error messages report both "value required" and "must not be null" for an empty field, for example. It seems to run 2 rounds of validations. Plus it does already work for editing existing objects.

Comment: @AamirAdnan (2) I really prefer not to do this kind of validation on a form level. Data integrity is maintained on two levels: (1) database check contraints, (2) Django Models. Validating on Models is supposed to work?